# Know which table is READ / UPDATE / INSERT / DELETE

Tags: postgresql

Context : I have a legacy PostgreSQL database (currently 9.5 but can be any newer version) and a tons of script / program acceding it.
All this script can do various operations on the table's row (READ, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE).

Problem : I don't know which script do what on which table, and it become really problematic when I when to modify some table structure (like make the primary key a SERIAL and not a plain bigint with "SELECT MAX(id) + 1" to have the next id ...). I have also some "ninja" script that connect to the database using god know forsaken login/pwd, and for legacy reason, I can't just change the pwd.

What I want to do : I want to know which table are "used" by wich connection (I can know which program do which connection).

So far, I tried to apply a trigger on every table that I want to supervise.
The main idea is to simply insert into a table "trace" that the "pg_backend_pid()" have do a "INSERT" into the table "foo" if the query
"INSERT INTO foo (bar) VALUES (10);"
But a trigger on a SELECT event doesn't exist, so it's not enough.

I activated all the logging that PostgreSQL 9.5 can offer

extract of postgresql.conf

> ## - What to Log -
>
> debug_print_parse = on
>
> debug_print_rewritten = on
>
> debug_print_plan = on
>
> debug_pretty_print = on
>
> log_checkpoints = on
>
> log_connections = on
>
> log_disconnections = on
>
> log_duration = on
>
> log_error_verbosity = terse
>
> log_hostname = on

But I can't find a way to get what I want.
There is the query plan that seem promising, but this "thing" is so frickkin' huge that I can't begin to understand how to read it (also, I don't find any documentation even is the EXPLAIN keyword documentation on how to read that !).

So I begin to be clueless.
Is there a way to do it ? Is the query plan the good lead ?

Comment: It looks like a typical use case for the [pgAudit](https://www.pgaudit.org) extension. The oldest version it supports is 9.5.

Comment: set `log_min_duration_statement` to 0 (or `log_statment` to `all`) and look in the logs.

Comment: thanks you, I will look into both of your suggestion.